# is  a variant of 廾, or is it another radical with another meaning?

Tags: kanji, radicals

廾 is part of kanjis like 弁 .  is part of kanjis like 発. In Wikipedia 廾 is listed to mean "2 hands" or "twenty". is  the same? or does it have another meaning?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the same modern graphic shape will always trace back to the same meaningful element. That's not true; often modern kanji components descend from entirely different elements, or are meaningless graphical strokes. Kanji elements don't necessarily have a fixed meaning, or even meaning at all (and they're often used for sound, rather than meaning). For example, 弁 is a graphical abbreviation of all of 辨瓣辯辮 on account of all being pronounced *ben*; it's thus unrelated to the meaning of the Chinese character 弁 which is a drawing of two hands holding a cap, meaning "cap".

Comment: (cont.) meanwhile, the bottom part of 発 is a graphic simplification of 發, which is a composition of 弓  "bow" + 癹 two feet plus a hand holding a tool (used for sound). But even if you find another kanji with an identical graphical element, its history and original meaning may be entirely different. Or it may be used for sound in one case, for meaning in the other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kanji_radicals_by_frequency

Comment: @boiko  I believe that you could post that as part of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly answering the question: no,「」is not a variant of「廾」, although under some very special circumstances they may be interpreted as being related.

> is part of kanjis like 発

Ideographic description sequences may list it as such out of *organisational convenience*, but the fact is the bottom of「発」is just a type of shorthand for the bottom of「發」.**「」is just a shape; don't try to interpret meaning into it.**

Because「」is not a character consciously created with a word in mind, it has no meaning at all, and the closest we can get is digging up definitions of things with similar shapes.

---

Similar shape (1): **Variant of「九」**, as recorded in [《字彙補》](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E5%BD%99%E8%A3%9C):

[image]

This is just another way of styling「九」in regular script.「九」originally depicted a bent arm; the meaning *nine* is a phonetic loan. Here are some other ways of stylising ancient forms of「九」(not necessarily in regular script):

[image]

Similar shape (2): **Variant of「攀」**, as recorded in [Jiyun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiyun):

[image]

This is the official [Shuowen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) variant, whereas「攀」is the modern form but also an older form than the Shuowen character, and is attested in the Warring States period. In digital form, the Shuowen character is more likely to be represented by「」. For reference, the Shuowen form looks like

[image]

depicting *pulling/climbing*, and is the *two hands*「廾」mentioned in the question turned inside out:

[image]

*Samples of*「廾」*. (Left) Oracle bone sample. (Right) Shuowen seal form.*

---

There is only one common variant of *two hands*「廾」:

[image]

As a character component, these two variants literally looked like two hands (as per the oracle bone and seal forms given above), and weren't distinguished until much later (with no semantic difference). Some common characters with this component:

- 「開」, two hands opening a latched door「閂」> *open*:

  [image]
- 「兵」, two hands holding an axe「斤」> *weapon, soldier*:

  [image]
- 「典」, two hands holding a bunch of scrolls > *book*:

  [image]
- 「興」, **four hands** lifting a tray「凡」(later「同」) > *rise* > *excitement, interest, pleasure*

  [image]
- 「弄」, two hands playing with a piece of jade「玉」> *to play around with, tamper with*

  [image]

---

Finally, *twenty* should not be considered as an important definition for「廾」. People may have written *twenty* this way in some books due to the similarity in shape of「廾」to「卄」and「廿」, but only the latter two hold the primary definition of *twenty*.